# Get first occurrence of a node that matches criteria during XSLT 1.0 transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to get the Machine/Properties/Axes/Axis/AxisID/Name value of the first occurrence where the criteria Machine/Properties/Axes/Axis/Type = Rotary so that I can populate the Top element with the Name element.

I tried the following XSLT template but it did not produce the right output:

```
 <xsl:template match="cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:Type='Rotary'][1]/cd:Rotaries/cd:Top">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Axis>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::cd:Properties/cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:AxisID/cd:Name" />
      </Axis>
      <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
      <IsManual>false</IsManual>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Desired Output for Top element:

```
<Top>
   <Axis>R1</Axis>
   <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
   <IsManual>false</IsManual>
</Top>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMachine xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Machine>
    <Price>120000</Price>
    <Properties>
      <Axes>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>X</Name>
            <Type>X</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>Y</Name>
            <Type>Y</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>Z</Name>
            <Type>Z</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>R1</Name>
            <Type>B</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Rotary</Type>
        </Axis>
        <Axis>
          <AxisID>
            <Name>R2</Name>
            <Type>C</Type>
          </AxisID>
          <Type>Linear</Type>
        </Axis>
      </Axes>
      <Ordering>XR1YR2Z</Ordering>
      <Rotaries>
        <Top i:nil="true" />
        <Bottom i:nil="true"/>
        <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
        <IsManual>false</IsManual>
        <Mode>222</Mode>
      </Rotaries>
    </Properties>
  </Machine>
</ArrayOfMachine>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `((//Machine/Properties/Axes/Axis[Type='Rotary'])[1])/AxisID/Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated]

In testing with `xsltproc` of libxslt 1.1.28, I find inconsistent, buggy behavior with respect to matching patterns with position predicates.  This version of `xsltproc` matches a template to one of the nodes in your example via this match expression:

```
cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:Type = 'Rotary'][1]
```

, and within that template it selects a non-empty node set via the expression

```
cd:Rotaries/cd:Top
```

.  The nodes selected that way should also be matched to a template with your expression

```
cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:Type='Rotary'][1]/cd:Rotaries/cd:Top
```

, but `xsltproc` in fact does not match any node of your input to a template with that for its match expresssion.  This is not necessarily related directly to your problem, but it's a reason to consider a variation on your approach.

In any event, the `select` expression in your `xsl:value-of` is certainly incorrect.  It selects a node set containing the `<cd:Name>` elements of *all* axes, not just the one having type `'Rotary'`, and converting that to a string yields the string value of the *first* node in the set.  That's not the one you want.  The inconsistency I described above notwithstanding, I find that a variation on your match expression does work for me as the `select` expression of an `xsl:value-of` to select the node you want.  Putting that together, then, this template works for me as you seem to want:

```
<xsl:template match="cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:Type='Rotary']/cd:Rotaries/cd:Top">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Axis>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::cd:Properties/cd:Axes/cd:Axis[cd:Type = 'Rotary'][1]/cd:AxisID/cd:Name" />
      </Axis>
      <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
      <IsManual>false</IsManual>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're describing as an "inconsistency".  The *match pattern* used by OP works perfectly well in XSLT 1.0, including when using the  `libxslt` processor. The problem is with the *select* expression used in the `xsl:value-of` instruction: without a similar predicate, it returns the value from the 1st axis, not from the 1st rotary axis as intended.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, the answer already describes the seeming inconsistency I found.  I am well prepared to accept that it is my expectations that are wrong, but you've not convinced me.  In particular, the OP's match pattern *does not* work with `xsltproc` of libxslt 1.1.28, in the sense that it does not match the associated template to any node. That is is consistent with the result the OP describes.  The lack of any output whatever is not consistent with the problem lying (only) with the `select` expression of the `xsl:value-of`.

Comment: I am afraid I still don't understand what you're saying. OP's match pattern does match a node in the given input. You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRJu If you're getting a different result, then your processor is non-conforming. However, I am getting the same result when running the same transformation using `xsltproc` in MacOS Sierra.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, libxslt 1.1.28 produces no output for your variation on the example, either, so I guess what I'm saying is that this version of libxslt is buggy, producing the inconsistency I describe.  Specifically, it matches the correct node via pattern `cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:Type = 'Rotary'][1]`, but does not match any node via the OP's pattern `cd:Machine/cd:Properties[cd:Axes/cd:Axis/cd:Type='Rotary'][1]/cd:Rotaries/cd:Top`, which just adds two child steps to the other.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am getting 
<Top>
   <Axis>X</Axis>
   <IsIndexed>false</IsIndexed>
   <IsManual>false</IsManual>
</Top> For the output. I was expecting the axis element value to be R1. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @markf78 As I said [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503118/get-first-occurrence-of-a-node-that-matches-criteria-during-xslt-1-0-transform/43504868?noredirect=1#comment74076574_43504868), you need to add a predicate to your select expression.